# Какой подход лучше в подключенни файлов для translation units?

Tags: c++

### Проблема

Хочу найти оптимальное решение проблемы подключения `headers` в `translation units`. И на данный момент, стою между двумя способами, которые мне известны:

### 1. Подключать `.h` только в `.cpp`

Плюсы:

- Обособление объявления (`.h`) от реализации (`.cpp`) со всеми её зависимостями
- Устранение возможности, когда `headers` начинают подключать друг друга по цепочке

Минусы:

- Каждый раз, когда мы подключаем `.h` мы должны также подключать другие `.h` от которых он зависит.

Например, у нас есть класс `GameState`. Он объявлен в `GameState.h` и реализован в `GameState.cpp`, где подключаются его зависимости, например: `State.h`, `Entity.h`.

Мы подключаем `GameState.h` в какой-нибудь другой `.cpp` и для него же и вместе с ним должны подключить его зависимости, то есть `State.h` и `Entity.h`.
Получается вместо одного `#include "GameState.h"` мы получем:

```
#include "State.h"
#include "Entity.h"
#include "GameState.h"
```

### 2. Подключать `.h` зависимости в реализуемый `.h`

Плюсы и минусы -> зеркальное отражение "плюсов и минусов" способа выше.

### Вопрос

Так какой способ будет лучше? Есть ли ещё какие-либо другие способы наиболее эффективно организовать этот процесс?

P.S. Про модули `C++20` знаю, но пока что не использую, так как большинство компиляторов поддерживают эту фичу только как экспериментальную. Но, если вы просто поднимите этот вопрос то, думаю, это только лишь обогатит обсуждение.

Comment: Ну если он все равно зависит от чего-то, и это что-то должно будет все равно быть включено, еще и обязательно ранее, чем зависимый файл - то на кой заставлять об этом помнить программиста?...

Comment: @Alex F, это понятно. Но всё равно, некоторые говорят, что даже с гвардами и прагмами всякими подключать .h в .h - не есть гуд. Вот я и хочу уже наконец поставить точку в этом вопросе как минимум для себя.

Comment: В каждый файл следует подключать **все** заголовочные файлы, имена из которых он использует, то бишь делать его самодостаточным. Например: в вашем заголовочном файле `mein.hpp` объявляется функция `::std::size_t count(void);`, которая затем реализуется в `mein.cpp`. Соответственно `mein.cpp` должен включать `mein.hpp` и они оба должны включать `cstddef`.

Comment: Конечно (2). Никогда не видел, чтобы использовали (1). *"некоторые говорят"* Кто говорит? *"Устранение возможности [кругового включения]"* Не очень понимаю, в чем тут плюс. Круговое включение обычно не очень сложно обнаружить, если оно появляется. В (1) их вообще не будет, да, но это как ампутировать ногу, чтобы она перестала чесаться. *"Обособление объявления (.h) от реализации (.cpp)"* Вот эту часть не понял.

Comment: У (1) есть еще один минус - IDE не смогут выдавать нормальные подсказки по коду в хедерах.